# Format date in mysql query that uses cast

Tags: mysql, date, time, casting

I've got this as the select part of my query:

```
SELECT cast(cast(exp_channel_titles.edit_date as char(14)) as datetime) AS Edit_Date
```

That takes data from a db in this format 20130501092128 and returns it in this format 2013-05-01 09:21:28

I can only assume it is some kind of magic as i don't fully understand how this works tbh.

But, i need to change the format of the date that it spits out to this format: %d/%m/%Y %k:%i:%s

I can honestly say i have no idea how to do this in that query, i've tried adding it as a param to datetime (is that even a mysql function?!?) but no joy and many other poor attempts that i wont go into.

If anyone can help, i'd be hugely grateful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySql automatically converts 20130501092128 to a date and time field, even if it is a VARCHAR or a INT, and you can just use this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(exp_channel_titles.edit_date, '%d/%m/%Y %k:%i:%s')
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/11792).

Comment: I had no idea that happened. You are a total life saver, at least i understand this query. Thank you so so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can change output format using `DATE_FORMAT()` function from MySQL. Here is the documentation post about it.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

You can change the output format into whatever format you want, but if you recieve that data into an application, modifies it and return that data to server (editing a row for example). Remember to reformat it into a valid date for MySQL.

If you dont know how to do it, just have to do this into your query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(cast(cast(exp_channel_titles.edit_date as char(14))
 as datetime), '%e/%m/%Y %k:%i:%s') AS Edit_Date
```